# Eclipse JDT get name of classes

Tags: eclipse, class, eclipse-jdt

I am using Eclipse JDT to obtain the name of all classes of every open projects in workspace, but until now I cannot do that...

```
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
IProject[] iprojects = workspace.getRoot().getProjects();

for (IProject ip : iprojects)
{
    if (ip.isOpen() == true)
    {
        IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(ip);

    IPackageFragment[] packages;
    try
    {
        packages = javaProject.getPackageFragments();

        for (IPackageFragment mypackage : packages)
        {
            if (mypackage.getKind() == IPackageFragmentRoot.K_SOURCE)
            {
                System.out.println("Source Name " + mypackage.getElementName());
                System.out.println("Number of Classes: " + mypackage.getClassFiles().length);
            }
            else if (mypackage.getKind() == IPackageFragmentRoot.K_BINARY)
            {
                System.out.println("Binary Name " + mypackage.getElementName());
                System.out.println("Number of Classes: " + mypackage.getClassFiles().length);
            }
        }
    } catch (JavaModelException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

With this I can only obtain **Number of Classes: 0** for every package in my project example!

What is wrong? Why I cannot obtain the classes of every packages and next obtain the name of every class?

--
Cheers, Zé Carlos

Comment: You know that getClassFiles() and getCompilationUnits() return different results, right?

And why aren't you using the SearchEngine instead?

Comment: From API:
getClassFiles() returns all of the class files in this package fragment but it is possible that a package fragment contains only compilation units.
getCompilationUnits() returns all of the compilation units in this package fragment but it is possible that a package fragment contains only class files.

Now I am confuse, what should I use?
About SearchEngine, I don't know anything about that, it's a better solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchEngine.searchAllTypeNames(...) methods.

Comment: I cannot understand the documentation of searchAllTypeNames, can you provide to me an example? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

From the Javadocs

> org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit - Represents an entire Java
>   compilation unit (source file with one of the Java-like extensions).
>   Compilation unit elements need to be opened before they can be
>   navigated or manipulated.
>
> org.eclipse.jdt.core.IClassFile - Represents an entire binary type
>   (single .class file).

There should be no class files in your projects because they are probably source projects. Hence look for ICompilationUnits.

Comment: There no classes files in my project?! When I compile the project I create the class files, right?!

Comment: Yes you do and the compiled classes go to the output folders or the 'bin' folders. However, here you want to work with the source files - so just use getCompilationUnits() instead of getClassFiles().

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be correct with your code. Thing is:
 1. It will work only if you use it in a plugin development project. That is, make a sample plugin and call this class form the base plugin class to test.
 2. It will list the name of the projects in the newly opened plugin tab. So make some example projects in the new eclipse window that you get on running it as "eclipse application".

I have a simpler code that works fine, try it:

import org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin;

public class GetProjectName {

```
public static IProject[] getProjects()

{

    IProject[] projects = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects();
    System.out.println(ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getName());

    System.out.println(" ****  "+ projects.length +"   ***");

    for (IProject project : projects) {
        System.out.println(project.getName());
    }



    return projects;

}
```

}